# Spin promela GPU

Tags: gpu, multicore, spin, promela

I am avaluating Spin using Promela for model checking, but processing time is an issue to me.
I have seen that I can use Multi Core to improve the calculation but what about GPU/Cuda support to speed up the calculations ? Can I do this at all ?

regards
Adrian

Answer (score 2):

GPU support is not included in Spin but is an active area of research.  Most SPIN problems that are slow enough to seek a speed up are also large enough to exceed the local memory on a GPU.  As a result the CPU memory needs to be used to store the explored state space and then memory bandwidth, CPU <==> GPU, swamp any computational speed increases.  If however, your state space is small then the GPU may be amenable to use; yet, Spin does not include such support.